# Laravel 7: Cannot update record in users table

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I've searched but couldn't find a working solution. I simply cannot update a specific field (status) in users table. I've added two additional fields in Laravel's auth users original table.

Here is the migration code:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);

        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
    });
}
```

I've also added fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password', 'role_id', 'status'];
```

Now the issue is I cannot update "status" field and the operation doesn't return any issue. I already have tried it with different approaches. Have a look at the code and guide me. TIA.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([]);

        // APPROACH # 1
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->status = $request->status;
        $user->save();

        // APPROACH # 2
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update([
            'status' => $request->status,
        ]);

        // APPROACH # 3
        User::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
    }
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/admin/user') }}/{{ $editRecord[0]->id }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @method('PUT')
    @csrf

    <select id="status" name="status" class="form-control">
        <option value="1" @if($editRecord[0]->status == 1) selected @endif>Active</option>
        <option value="0" @if($editRecord[0]->status == 0) selected @endif>In-Active</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Finally the route:

```
Route::put('/admin/user/{id}', 'Admin\PortalController@update');
```

Comment: dd the id to see if its received

Comment: Yes it is received. $request->status is also received.

Comment: dd($user) after alteration, and check what shows?

Comment: what is the output of `dd($request->all());` ?

Comment: @shams it gives "App\User" array where in #original the "status" value is "1" which is correct.

Comment: @sta the output is 
`array:3 [▼
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "_token" => "8uLYqPkptBKUTgFLjUa1v98T3d1F6mHdgyZ53AY9"
  "status" => "1"
]`

Comment: Are you using ant try catch statement in your query?

Comment: @sta I just put `try catch` inside the controller function after reading your comment. But still no exception

Comment: Try this Fluent Query: `\DB::table('users')->where('id', $id)->update(['status'=> 1]);`

Comment: Fluent Query didn't work either.

Comment: Do you check your database, make sure data inserted or not?

Answer (score 0):

Then code is working fine may be you forget to redirect back with success message. you should try below -

```
    if($user->save()){
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'updated successfully');
     } else {
       return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'something went wrong');
     }
```

Then in blade file -

```
     @if(session()->has('message'))
       <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session()->get('message') }}
       </div>
     @endif
    
     @if(session()->has('error'))
       <div class="alert alert-danger">
          {{ session()->get('error') }}
       </div>
     @endif
```

Comment: No. I've already added those success and error messages. The controller is even redirecting to another page with success message displayed. BUT the db table column field "status" is not being updated.